# Adding code to end of Joomla menu module (mod_mainmenu)?

Tags: joomla, menu, module

I would like to add code to a menu by modifying the Joomla `mod_mainmenu` module in Joomla 1.5 and I just need a standard "list" type menu.

This is the standard output:

```
<div class="moduletable">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want it structured like this:

```
<div class="moduletable">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Link</span></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="justify"></span>
```

As you see, I want to add the span tag with the justify class. I do this is to make my `ul` menu with floats, justify correctly.

Could someone explain to me what, where and in which file, I need to add the needed code to?

I am also interested in other methodologies to do this without altering the module code if anyone can link me to example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy the tmpl file of mod_mainmenu to

Copy file from `Joomlaroot => modules => mod_mainmenu => tmpl => default.php` to 
`Joomla Root => templates => yourSelectedTemplate => html => mod_mainmenu => default.php`

Just append your code after last line of code in this file.

Comment: Thanks for that, but I would really need someone to explain to me WHAT and WHERE and in WHICH file I need to add my code for this to work. Maybe I should have been more specific about that, sry!

Comment: @user1129759 : i have changed my answer.

Comment: I tried this, I added the code: `echo '<span class="justify"></span>';` at the very end of default.php but it didnt work. Did i misunderstand it? I even replaced the default.php in mod_mainmenu. Wierd thing is when I temporarily removed default.php from the module there was no error in my webpage.?

Comment: it is working at my end. Probably it won't show anything there is some text in span.

Comment: hmm... strange, cause Im looking at the source code and the span isn't there. The ul ends and right after that the div ends. Can you send me your code or an URL perhaps? And thank you!

Comment: i am testing at local end. try user `echo '<span class="justify">My Name</span>';`

Comment: You were right! Because I had nohing in the span-tag it didnt output anything (strange?). I will try making this work with it outputting &nbsp; &nbsp; . Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a directory in /modules/mod_mainmenu with mod_mainmenu.php, but I think the menu is generated (php), not as static as you write there.
Try to download a menu component/module and see if you can change that.

Comment: Thanks, yes thats correct and I am aware that its generated. The code I wrote is the static that is generated AND the static that I want it to generate. There are a couple of php-files in the module -> helper.php, legacy.php, mod_mainmenu.php and tmpl/deafult.php. The file mod_mainmenu.php I think is for the backend andministrator options only. I tried editing the legacy.php at line 373 but no success.